# Python 101 : Komodo edit - code not running in command

Tags: python, komodo

I have just opened up Komodo edit and can't run any code.

I just get this message in the command output:

> /usr/bin/python: can't open file 'Python3-1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

What do I do? I installed python3 again. Do I need to install it in the right place?

Answer (score 1):

I think it say for you - `I can't find your file`.

You should try to check path to you file.

Then you should try to run your code from terminal. Open terminal app (gnome-terminal, konsole, xfce-terminal or etc. what you always using for this) and try run directly you file in you folder like this:
`python Python3-1.py` or `python3 Python3-1.py` or `python3 -m Python3-1.py`.

If all works fine - check you Komodo settings.`Edit -> Preferences` in `Language` block check in Python `Default Python Interpreter`

If not help you -please update you question for more information.

P.S. and you should try VS Code for python development. It have awesome integrated terminal and you can learing run all programs on command line, like you will do it in real life. Komodo Edit good editor, but not the best for this.